# Why is my '+' operator considered as a new line character?

Tags: c, newline, user-input

The following code is for a modular calculator problem. The input data is:

```
 5
+3
* 7
+10
* 2
* 3
+1
% 11
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char oper;
    int number,result;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    result=number;
    do
    {
        oper=getchar();
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&number);
        if(oper=='+')
        {
            result=result+number;
        }
        else if(oper=='*')
        {
            result=result*number;
        }
        printf("%c %d %d ",oper,number,result);
    }while(oper!='%');
    result=result%number;
    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
3 5 
 3 5 * 7 35 
 10 35 
 10 35 * 2 70 
 2 70 * 3 210 
 1 210 
 1 210 % 11 210 1
```

I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: Note that doing `fflush(stdin)` is an extension of some runtime libraries, it's explicitly marked as undefined behavior in the C specification.

Comment: As for your problem, the newline *is* a character in its own right, so of course [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) will return that.

Comment: Also note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an *`int`*.

Comment: I tried scanf("%c%d",&oper,&number);. This doesen't work either.

Comment: Your input text is `" 5\n3+\n* 7\n"`... Those `\n` characters are there, and they're being read by `getchar()`.

Comment: @Cornstalks But they aren't being read when the input is *. It happens only for +.

Comment: the code is explicitly expecting the input in a specific order.  To make a calculator application, either one of two things needs to be done.  1) push values/operators onto the stack and only do the math when all parts of an operator are available.  2) use reverse polish notation (where the operator is entered after the expressions for that operator are available.)   3) each operator entry places the code into a 'mode' where it accumulates the remaining value(s) before performing the operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
oper=getchar();
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&number);
```

with

```
scanf(" %c", &oper);
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. But now I have trouble with huge data. Long int, double and float values are not giving me the desired output.

Comment: @emjay if you use `double number,result;` ,  use `scanf("%lf", &number);printf("%f", number);`, when `long int number;` then `scanf("%ld", &number);printf("%ld", number);`

Answer (score 1):

If you write `scanf(" %c", &operator)`, the space before the `%c` in `" %c"` will consume any number of whitespace characters before reading a single character.

Also, `scanf` will return `EOF` on a matching failure. You can use that as the condition for your `while` loop.

One more suggestion: before performing an operation, store the `result` in a `previous` variable so that you can print the value before and after the operation. This will result in user-friendly output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char operator;
  int number, previous, result;
  scanf("%d", &number);
  result = number;
  while (scanf(" %c", &operator) != EOF) {
    previous = result;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (operator == '+') {
      result += number;
    } else if (operator == '-') {
      result -= number;
    } else if (operator == '*') {
      result *= number;
    } else if (operator == '/') {
      result /= number;
    } else if (operator == '%') {
      result %= number;
    }
    printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", previous, operator, number, result);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find it better to use `fgets()` than `scanf()`/`getchar()` (alternatively, if you are using C99, `gets_s()` -- although I still prefer `fgets()` for maximum portability to older compiler environments) for all user-based input, then if necessary use `sscanf()`, `strtol()` (and the like) to convert the string into other data types, as this will read data by line in a way that is buffer-safe and you won't have to worry about things left in the input buffer. **This is especially true for user-based input which is never well-formed (due to typos, etc)**. `scanf()` really only works well when reading from well-formed input files.

With that in mind, I'd would write the code more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[80];
  char oper;
  int number,result;
  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  sscanf(buf, "%d",&number);
  printf("   saw input: %d\n", number );
  result=number;
  do
  {
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%c %d",&oper, &number);
    printf("   saw input: %c %d\n", oper, number );
    printf("   computing: %d %c %d\n", result, oper, number );
    if(oper=='+') {
      result=result+number;
    }
    else if(oper=='*') {
      result=result*number;
    }
    else if(oper=='%') {
      result=result%number;
    }
    printf("   result   : %d\n", result );
  } while( oper!='%' );
return 0;
}
```